# Angular : Have multiple functions in one Service

Tags: angularjs, service

Is it possible to have multiple functions in one service ?

I have this in my book service :

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
            .module('app.core')
            .service('BookService', BookService);

        BookService.$inject = ['$resource'];
        /* @ngInject */
        function BookService($resource) {
            return $resource('/api/book/:id', {
                id: '@id'
            }, {
                'get': {
                    method: 'GET',
                    cache: true
                },
              'query': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                cache: true
            },
            });
        }
})()
```

But in the same service i want to have another function where i will pass other parameters, ex  :

```
 return $resource('/api/book/:name', {
                name: '@name'
            }, {
                'get': {
                    method: 'GET',
                    cache: true
                },
               'query': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                cache: true
            },
            });
```

My controller looks like this and has two differents calls:

```
BookService.get({
                id: 2
            }, function(book) {})

BookService.get({
                name: "bookTitle"
            }, function(book) {})
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can. Just define the functions within the service. At the end, return an object that contains all the functions you want to expose to the consumers of the service. Edit: this works for factories. For services, see nathan's answer.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app.core')
        .factory('BookService', BookService);

        BookService.$inject = ['$resource'];
        /* @ngInject */
        function BookService($resource) {
            var getById = function(id){
                return $resource('/api/book/:id', {
                    id: id
                }, {
                    'get': {
                        method: 'GET',
                        cache: true
                    }
                });
            };

            var getByName = function(name) {
                return $resource('/api/book/:name', {
                    name: name
                }, {
                    'get': {
                        method: 'GET',
                        cache: true
                    }
                });
            };

            return {
                getById: getById,
                getByName: getByName
            };

        }
})()
```

Comment: This method of returning an object is what a factory is for.

Comment: You are right! Just thought of it myself when I read your answer. I'll change it to factory

Comment: Ok, so i just need to replace BookService.get({
                id: 2
            }, function(book) {}) by BookService.getById(id).get({
                id: 2
            }, function(book) {}) ? Right ?

Comment: Just $scope.book = BookService.getById(id); will do, no need for the callback

Comment: I will need a call back cause i will not only have .get but i will also have other parameters like .query, .save. etc. See my updated question

Answer (score 5):

When using a service you can attach functions to `this`. In that way you can have multiple functions in one service. for example:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
        .module('app.core')
        .service('BookService', BookService);

    BookService.$inject = ['$resource'];
    /* @ngInject */
    function BookService($resource) {
        this.fun1 = function(){
            return $resource('/api/book/:id', {
                id: '@id'
            }, {
                'get': {
                    method: 'GET',
                    cache: true
                }
            });
        }
        this.fun2 = function(){
            return $resource('/api/book/:name', {
                name: '@name'
            }, {
                'get': {
                    method: 'GET',
                    cache: true
                }
            });
        }
    })()
```

You can then access the functions with `BookService.fun1()` and `Bookservice.fun2()`

If attaching the functions to an object and then returning that object in the way that fikkatra did makes more sense, then use a factory instead of a service.

Comment: I tried BookService.fun1({ id: 2 }, function(book) { scope.book= [book]; console.log(scope.book); }); But now my bookis null while it wasnt null with my initial code

Comment: @user708683 your `book` is likely null because the scope of this service is different from the scope of your controller. Try passing book in as a parameter of fun1 if you want to use it inside the function.